# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization in Maps

Tags: java, json, jackson

In prior cases, I've used Jackson's (Jackson 1.9, hosted by Codehaus) polymorphic serialization to serialize lists of format `List<MyBaseType>` into the appropriate object types.

Now, I need to serialize a `Map<String,MyBaseType>` and deserialize it.  I see that when the value gets written, I'm getting the proper format I would expect:

`{"className":"IndexRecord","id":0,"fields":{"className":"FieldMap","df12":{"className":"CustomStringType","value":"ralph"}}}`

Where I've tried a few things, including a wrapper implementation of the map (`FieldMap`).  Whenever I try to deserialize this, I get

`Could not resolve type id 'CustomStringType' into a subtype of 'MyBaseType'`

I do have everything annotated properly, including `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubType`

Here's a very simple case to make it happen.  Assume you have these POJOs

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IndexRecord {
    private int id;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
    private Map<String,IndexValue> fields;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeName("IndexValue")
public class IndexValue {
    private String value;
}
```

When I run the following test harness:

```
IndexRecord indexRecord = new IndexRecord();
IndexValue iv = new IndexValue();
iv.setValue("ralph");
indexRecord.getFields().put("foo",iv);
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String data = om.writeValueAsString(indexRecord);
System.out.println("Data is "+data);
IndexRecord result = om.readValue(data,IndexRecord.class);
```

Based on some docs out there, it looks like I may need to implement a custom deserializer.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you upgrade to Jackson 2? It worked for me with that version of the library.

Comment: I may try upgrading.  I didn't want to redo all of my annotations yet.  For anyone who does come across this, it was fixed by implementing a custom Deserializer.

Comment: Where the CustomStringType type name is defined?